How to get checked checkbox vaule inside ngFor/ngIf?
I have data like so:
 const List: Array<Item> = [
       { id: 1, name: 'somename' }
       ...
]

Then html looks like this:
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index;">
     <div class="grid">

           <mat-checkbox *ngIf="item.id > 4;" #{{item.name}}
                         value="false"
                         type="checkbox">
           </mat-checkbox>

            <mat-form-field *ngIf="item.id <= 4">
                 <input formControlName="{{item.name}}" matInput value="" type="number"/>
            </mat-form-field>
                
            <mat-form-field *ngIf="item.id > 4 && item.name.checked">
                 <input formControlName="{{item.name}}" matInput value="" type="number"/>
            </mat-form-field>
      </div>
</ng-container>

NgFor iterates through the array and creates mat-checkbox's and mat-form-field's.
There is form-field for every item in the array but only some form-field items get checkbox.
Form-field that do not get checkbox are visible at all times.
Form-field that DO get checkbox are ONLY visible after corresponding checkbox is checked.
My problem is how do I get the form-field to be shown after it's checkbox is checked ?
The #{{item.name.checked}} binding isn't working
Edit:
const List: Array<Item> = [
       { id: 1, name: 'somename', class: 'hide' }
       ...
]

<mat-checkbox #checkBoxId class="{{item.class}}"
             type="checkbox">
</mat-checkbox>

SCSS

.hide {
    display: none;
}


When you use a template reference variable inside a *ngFor (or inside a @for) the "scope" is relative to this loop
What mean this? that you use the "same" variable name (in the code checkBoxId)
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index;">
     <div class="grid">
           <mat-checkbox *ngIf="item.id > 4;" #checkBoxId
                         value="false"
                         type="checkbox">
           </mat-checkbox>
           <!-- you can use--->
           {{checkboxId.checked}}

           <mat-form-field *ngIf="item.id > 4 && checkBoxId.checked">
                 <input formControlName="{{item.name}}" matInput 
                     type="number"/>
            </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
          

NOTE: When you use ReactiveFormsControls not use "value", just give value to the formControl.
Update As it's indicate in comments (thanks for the advise @Dozobus) ther'e a problem when the mat-check is under a *ngIf. we can replace the *ngIf by [style.display]="i<=4?'non':null"
or use
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let control of  form.controls|keyvalue;let i=index" >
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="items[i].id<=4">
      <input matInput [formControlName]="items[i].name" />
    </mat-form-field><br/>
    <ng-container *ngIf="items[i].id>4">
      <section>
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" #checkinId>Check me!</mat-checkbox>
      </section>
      <mat-form-field *ngIf="checkinId.checked">
        <input matInput [formControlName]="items[i].name" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</form>

NOTE:In submit we need take account this mat-checkbox, we can use some like
//use ViewChildren to "reach" the checkboxes
@ViewChildren('checkinId') checkboxes!:QueryList<MatCheckbox>

submit()
{
    const data={...this.form.value}
    this.items.forEach((x:any,index:number)=>{
       if (x.id>4)
       {
         const checkBox=this.checkboxes.find((_,i:number)=>i==index-4) 
         if (checkBox && !checkBox.checked)
             data[x.name]=""
       }
    })
    ...do something with "data"
}

NOTE2: In stackblitz I put diferents ways to mannage the problem using the new @for and @if

It throws error: "NG9: Property 'checkBoxId' does not exist on type 'ListComponent'. on this line -> " <mat-form-field *ngIf="item.id > 4 && checkBoxId.checked">"
Btw, thanks for the value hint.

Ok, got it working. What you said was correct. It was the ngIf on the chceckbox element that f**ed it up. I removed it and added custom class to them and hid them with css. Thanks

You can use also in the html [style.display]="item.id<=4?'none':null"

@dozobus, I update the answer with some point to take account.

A refactoring my answer
well, my before answer need in submit check the values of the checkbox.
We can take advantage that, when a formControl is disabled the form.value omit this formControl.
So, first make a directive disabled
@Directive({
  selector:'input[disabled]',
  standalone:true

})
export class DisabledDirective
{
  @Input('disabled') set _(value:boolean)
  {
    this.control && this.control.control && 
              this.control.control[value?'disable':'enable']()
  }
  constructor(@Optional() private control:NgControl){}
}

This it's necessary because we need use the methods disableand enable to disable/enable a formControl.
I like more that the "items" array have a property "optional", so can be, e.g.
items=[{id:1,name:'input1'},{id:2,name:'input2'},{id:3,name:'input3'},
       {id:4,name:'input4',optional:true},{id:5,name:'input5',optional:true}]

And we create the formGroup as
form=new FormGroup(this.items.reduce((a:any,item:any)=>{
    a[item.name]=new FormControl({value:'',disabled:item.optional});
    return a
  },{}));

Well, we can to have an .html like (see that we disable the control insteadOf put under a *ngIf
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let control of  form.controls|keyvalue;let i=index" >
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="!items[i]?.optional">
      <input matInput [formControlName]="items[i].name" />
    </mat-form-field><br/>
    <ng-container *ngIf="items[i]?.optional">
      <section>
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" #checkinId>Check me!</mat-checkbox>
      </section>
      <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [formControlName]="items[i].name" 
               [disabled]="!checkinId.checked"/>
      </mat-form-field>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</form>

The last piece of the jigsaw is add in component.css
.mat-form-field-disabled{
  display: none;
}

a stackblitz

The checkboxes were only for showing/hiding corresponding form-field element.
So form didn't need to check against it's value but thank you for the effort, much appreciated.

@dozobus, but.. how you know if is unchecked? The formcontrol still have value if you check-->add value-->uncheck

I guess Angular engine will know because it works as expected even tho theres only #id and (click) func on it.
